# Iterate through javascript object to find a match

Tags: javascript, loops, object, match

I'm trying to loop through an object and find a specific match. When I find a match, I want to pull the other key value pairs in the object. So if I have an object in this form:

```
[{"ID":"3","NAME":"John","Age":"15"},{"ID":"4","NAME":"Mike","Age":"10"},{"ID":"5","NAME":"Tim","Age":"18"},{"ID":"6","NAME":"Ken","Age":"20"}]
```

and I have a search/match value

```
var MatchValue = 4;
```

How can I iterate through my object to find the "ID" that equals 4 and display the "NAME" and "AGE" from the object? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. #JsonNoob.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is filter your array. You can do this with JavaScript's `filter` function. This code will get you the elements where the ID is equal to 4.

You can then access this object's properties with either dot or bracket notation.

```
var myObject = array.filter(function(element) {
    return element.ID === '4';
}

console.log(myObject.name);     // Prints name to console
console.log(myObject.age);      // Prints age to console
```

If you have a browser from the stone ages, you can do this

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
    throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in this) {
        var val = this[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this))
        res.push(val);
      }
    }
    return res;
  };
}
```

I got this from another Stack Overflow answer, but I can explain it.

This checks if your browser has the `Array.prototype.filter` function. Some older versions of IE don't have it, so you can then define the function manually.

Comment: I get this error about array.filter not being a function. Is there some sort of alternative>?